# Divide n into x random parts

Tags: random, lua, numbers, dice, divide

What I need to achieve is basically x dice rolls = n sum but backwards.

So let's create an example:

The dice has to be rolled 5 times (min. sum 5, max. sum 30) which means:

```
x = 5
```

Let's say in this case the sum that was rolled is 23 which means:

```
n = 23
```

So what I need is to get the any of the possible single dice roll combinations (e.g. 6, 4, 5, 3, 5)

What I could make up in my mind so far is:

1. Create 5 random numbers.
2. Add them up and get the sum.
3. Now divide every single random number by the sum and multiply by the wanted number 23.
4. The result is 5 random numbers that equal the wanted number 23.

The problem is that this one returns random values (decimals, values below 1 and above 6) depending on the random numbers. I can not find a way to edit the formula to only return integers >= 1 or <= 6.

Comment: To generate all possible combinations, I don't think using random numbers is the solution.

Comment: I do not need all possible combinations, I do only need one random combination for the given number each run.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to scale it up by far the easiest way is to re-randomize it until you get the right sum. It takes milliseconds on any modern cpu. Not pretty tho.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/lua

math.randomseed(os.time())

function divs(n,x)
  local a = {}

  repeat
    local s = 0
    for i=1,x do
      a[i] = math.random(6)
      s = s + a[i]
    end
  until s==n

  return a
end

a = divs(23,5)
for k,v in pairs(a) do print(k,v) end
```

Comment: You only need to call `math.randomseed` once per program. So it'd be wiser to call it outside `divs`. Also, use local variables `a` and `s` in `divs`.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting problem. Here's my take:

EDIT: I missed the fact that you needed them to be dice rolls. Here's a new take. As a bonus, you can specify the number of sides of the dices in an optional parameter.

```
local function getDiceRolls(n, num_rolls, num_sides)
  num_sides = num_sides or 6
  assert(n >= num_rolls, "n must be greater than num_rolls")
  assert(n <= num_rolls * num_sides, "n is too big for the number of dices and sides")

  local rolls = {}
  for i=1, num_rolls do rolls[i] = 1 end

  for i=num_rolls+1, n do
    local index = math.random(1,num_rolls)
    while rolls[index] == num_sides do
      index = (index % num_rolls) + 1
    end
    rolls[index] = rolls[index] + 1
  end

  return rolls
end

-- tests:

print(unpack(getDiceRolls(21, 4))) -- 6 4 6 5
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(21, 4))) -- 5 5 6 5
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(13, 3))) -- 4 3 6
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(13, 3))) -- 5 5 3
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(30, 3, 20))) -- 9 10 11
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(7, 7)))  -- 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(7, 8)))  -- error
print(unpack(getDiceRolls(13, 2)))  -- error
```

Comment: This solution does not respect the restriction that the addends be the result of dice throwing, that is, between 1 and 6.

Comment: @lhf: You are totally right, I overlooked that on the description. I've rewritten my answer with a new algorithm which implements that.

Answer (score 0):

If the # of rolls does not change wildly, but the sum does, then it would be worth creating a lookup table for combinations of a given sum. You would generate every combination, and for each one compute the sum, then add the combination to a list associated to that sum. The lookup table would look like this:

```
T = {12 = {{1,2,3,4,2},{2,5,3,1,1},{2,2,2,3,3}, ...}, 13=....}
```

Then when you want to randomly select a combo for n=23, you look in table for key 23, the list has all combos with that sum, now just randomly pick one of them. Same for any other number.